# i want to record video with flashlight in flutter ,anyone know any plugin or way to do it in flutter

Tags: flutter, plugins, camera, video-recording, flashlight

I want to record video along with flashlight turned on,
I tried many packages but none of are working,
Any body know how to do this in flutter.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably just use these 2 packages in combination.

For camera, the Camera package: https://pub.dev/packages/camera.

And for flashlight, the flashlight package: https://pub.dev/packages/flashlight.

If you face errors in this, please do comment below.